# Oracle Collect Over Analytical Function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, analytic-functions

Is it possible to use the 10g collect command as an analytical function by using OVER PARTITION or some other way?

e.g.

```
SELECT COLLECT(x) OVER (PARTITION BY y)
FROM table
```

Every time I try this there is a ora 3113 exception saying 'end-of-file on communication channel'

PS. I know I need to cast the result to make it useful, but for simplicities sake I'm leaving it out for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COLLECT is not an analytical function, but can be used as a group function.

```
SELECT y, COLLECT(x) FROM table GROUP BY y
```

(Interesting, though:  COLLECT is not listed as being an analytical function, but if I try to use it that way as in your example it appears to work at first, then stops after outputting some of the results and gives ORA-03113 as you said.)